# match against IN join conditon

Tags: mysql, sql

How to satisfy below condition on join without where condition?

```
SELECT *
FROM xyz
JOIN abc ON 
  MATCH(xyz.p) AGAINST(abc.h,abc.i,abc.j IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

here xyz AND abc represent TABLES
xyz.p, abc.h,abc.i,abc.j represent COLUMNS

Comment: Where's your source code?

Comment: I can't give original tables. Thats why only i given mockup structure here

Answer (score 0):

It can be a little tricky to find the relevant documentation, but you cannot do what you want.  In the [section on full text restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-restrictions.html):

> - The argument to AGAINST() must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row.

I don't think MySQL offers an efficient way to do what you want.  However, if you ask another question, it might be possible to solve your particular problem.

Comment: Yes, can you suggest any solution for my problem

Comment: @chm . . . You haven't described a *problem*.  You have described a *syntax error*.  This addresses the syntax error.  If you want help actually doing something ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.